# how to change layout fo candidateView for my custom keyboard in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

i am making a custom keyboard with the help of android softkeyboard(which is provided with the sdk) i am showing word suggestion(or word prediction) on candidate view. it look like this....https://www.dropbox.com/s/p14gzaybaj5c18o/auto_correction.PNG?dl=0
but i wanted to show the suggestion like this.... https://www.dropbox.com/s/bkwnigmcswyn2wf/auto_correction_2.PNG?dl=0

how can i do such modification? My CandidateView class is remain exactly like default softkeyboard source code. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, Your Images are corrupted.
I'm guessing that it is the same problem everyone faced while working on the soft keyboard from the android sample code.
I found the perfect solution that should work [refrence](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/yp7c7zsUSlo).
Just override the following method in the InputMethodService.

```
//added for candidateView size adjusting
@Override
public void onComputeInsets(InputMethodService.Insets outInsets) {
    super.onComputeInsets(outInsets);
    if (!isFullscreenMode()) {
        outInsets.contentTopInsets = outInsets.visibleTopInsets;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onCreateCandidateView returns the view that's put into the candidate view.  You can return a view that looks any way you want.